# Images in a UItableview not being searched with the data

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` which contains names in each row alongwith images for each name. When on searching the particular name gets searched, the images are not searched for the same `UITableViewCell`. The image of the first row or the cell remains the same. How can I search for the images also?

I have uploaded the Images of the search issue.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcvtU.png"TableView "

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmsIv.png"Search In Tableview "

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
} 
if(temp==1)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [newarray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{     
    cell.textLabel.text= [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you maintaining the model for the datasource.
or you having two nsmutable array for the image and text.

please clear the scnario.

Comment: are you working with two arrays? Is there any connection with those two array

Comment: How is your UITableView being populated?

Comment: post the code you use in cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: I have 2 arrays one for the data search array and the other for the images "imagearray". If I search for the names there is no issue but if I search for the images using the same method, the images are not searched

Comment: When You are search then How to Know searching by text ya image name, so you manange the array ? when text array no match then search by iamge then sove your prblem

Comment: Aalok Parikh There are 2 arrays one for the image and the other for the array of names.

Comment: Omar Abdelhafith posted the code plz review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have newarray mutable for the name items, you must create a newarrayimages too.
So alloc and init newarrayimages like newarray and add:

```
if(temp==1)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //line to add
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[newarrayimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
```

try this and let me know.
by

Comment: I have tried this before but it still doesnt work. The images remain attached to their own cell.

Comment: and if you try to change with an integer the index of newarrayimages? try to log newarrayimages, how many object there are?

Comment: I get the number of rows for the names but for the images there is no value

Comment: So, there is a problem when you popolate the array object. Post the code of this array and the method